# ReactJS add table rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I want an app.js that imports a component, that generates a row in a table for each element in an array.

```
import myRows from './myRows';
const myApp = ({ values}) => {
return (
   
    <div>
  <div>        
        {values.map((entry, index) => {
            return <myRows entry={entry} key={index}/>
        })}
    </div>
    </div>

)
```

}
...

```
const myRows = ({ entry}) => {
    return (

      **ROW ENTRY like row name = entry.name**


    )
}
```

...

Maybe I should create in the my App.js a table and create in the map function a row for each entry in values? Idk how to do that.
I want a simple table where each row is created with each entry in values
My idea is not working and mybe it is stupid and there are many better ways..

```
import myRows from './myRows';
const myApp = ({ values}) => {
return (
        <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>2</th>
                        <th>3</th>
                        <th>4</th>
                        <th>5</th>
                        <th>6</th>
                        <th>7</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     {values.map((entry, index) => {
            return <myRows entry={entry} key={index}/>
        })}
                </tbody>
            </table> 
       
   

)
```

}
...

```
 const myRows = ({ entry}) => {
    return (

                    <tr>
                        <th>entry.name</th>
                        <td>entry.secondName</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>D1</td>
                        <td>entry.value22</td>
                        <td>E3</td>
                        <td>E4/</td>
                    </tr>


    )
}
```

...

Comment: What is the problem with this code ? I can already see that there is an error in your myRows component, you have to use brackets to access variables in the HTML, like this: <th>{entry.name}</th>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `index` as key. Each entry should have a unique identifier; either an `id` or you can interpolate some values to create a unique key for each row (e.g `key={${row.name}_${row.createdAt}}`

```
const App = ({ array }) => {
  return <table>
    <tbody>
      { array.map(row => <Row data={row} key={row.id} />) }
    </tbody>
  </table>
}

const Row = ({ data }) => {
  return <tr>
    <td>{data.name}</td>
    <td>{data.created}</td>
    ...
  </tr>
}
```